# Set extent in a webmap Esri

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, extents

I'm creating a storymap from a developers tutorial I found on Esri. The point of the tutorial is to insert an additional reference map. Everything is working well but I want the extent to closely focus on Texas. I can manipulate the extent but can't get it where I want it and adjusting the xmin and other values seem to throw me at unexpected places.

```
// Loading all required dojo and esri modules used in index map
require([
    'dojo/topic',
    'dojo/_base/array',
    'dojo/dom-geometry',
    'esri/map',
    'esri/layers/CSVLayer',
    'esri/Color',
    'esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol',
    'esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer',
], function(
    topic,
    array,
    domGeom,
    Map,
    CSVLayer,
    Color,
    SimpleMarkerSymbol,
    UniqueValueRenderer
) {
    // Custom Javascript to be executed while the application is initializing goes here

    // The application is ready
    topic.subscribe("tpl-ready", function(){

        // Custom Javascript to be executed when the application is ready goes here


        // CONFIGURATION VARIABLES START
        // Update the label fields for those used in your CSV file. Be sure that it matches
        // exactly (including case)
        var LabelField = 'Label';
        var StoryIndexField = 'StoryIndex';
        var ActiveField = 'Active';
        // Change the colors of the default and active symbols on the map.
        // Color documentation available here:
        // https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/Color.html
        var defaultMarkerColor = new Color([114, 100, 87, 0.7]);
        var activeMarkerColor = new Color([0, 105, 0, 0.9]);
        // The path to your csv file.
        var csvPath = 'resources/index-map/index-map-layer.csv';
        // CONFIGURATION VARIABLES END

        // variable stores currently selected graphic
        var selectedGraphic = false;

        // Removes the help text tooltip after the user first clicks on the map
        $('#index-map').click(function(){
            $('#index-map-helper').removeClass('active');
        });

        // Create the index map
        var indexMap = new Map('index-map',{
            // Change the following options to set the default view of your index map.
            // Option documentation is here:
            // https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1
            basemap: 'hybrid',
            extent: new esri.geometry.Extent({ xmin: -96.972500, ymin:33.139300, xmax: -96.872300, ymax: 33.188300, spatialReference: {  wkid: 3857 }}),
            zoom: 3,
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 20,
            // You don't need to change these
            logo: false,
            showAttribution: false
        });

        // Load CSV File as point later
        var indexMapLayer = csv = new CSVLayer(csvPath);

        // Create simple point symbols
        var activeMarker =  new SimpleMarkerSymbol('solid', 15, null, activeMarkerColor);
        var defaultMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol('solid', 12, null, defaultMarkerColor);

        // Change the CSV Layer renderer to use the symbols we just created
        var renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer(defaultMarker,ActiveField);
        renderer.addValue('TRUE', activeMarker);
        indexMapLayer.setRenderer(renderer);

        // Add CSV layer to map
        indexMap.addLayer(indexMapLayer);

        // Select current section in index map on Loading
        setIconDisplay(app.data.getCurrentSectionIndex());

        // Add map events
        indexMapLayer.on('click',function(event){
            $('#index-map-helper').removeClass('active');
            hideIndexMapInfo();
            topic.publish('story-navigate-section', event.graphic.attributes[StoryIndexField]);
        });

        indexMapLayer.on('mouse-over',function(event){
            indexMap.setCursor('pointer');
            setIndexMapInfo(event.graphic);
        });

        indexMapLayer.on('mouse-out',function(){
            indexMap.setCursor('default');
            hideIndexMapInfo();
        });

        indexMap.on('extent-change',function(){
            indexMap.setCursor('default');
            hideIndexMapInfo();
            moveSelectedToFront();
        });

        topic.subscribe('story-load-section', setIconDisplay);

        // Select current section in index map (Update symbol color)
        function setIconDisplay(index){
            selectedGraphic = false;
            if (index !== null){
                array.forEach(indexMapLayer.graphics,function(g){
                    if (g.attributes[StoryIndexField].toString() === index.toString()){
                        g.attributes[ActiveField] = 'TRUE';
                        if(g.getDojoShape()){
                            selectedGraphic = g;
                            g.getDojoShape().moveToFront();
                        }
                        indexMap.centerAt(g.geometry);
                    }
                    else{
                        g.attributes[ActiveField] = 'FALSE';
                    }
                });
                indexMapLayer.redraw();
            }
        }

        // Make sure selected point is on top.
        function moveSelectedToFront(){
            if (selectedGraphic) {
                selectedGraphic.getDojoShape().moveToFront();
            }
        }

        // Hide point tooltip
        function hideIndexMapInfo(){
            $('#index-map-info').hide();
        }

        // Show point tooltip
        function setIndexMapInfo(graphic){
            $('#index-map-info').html(graphic.attributes[LabelField]);
            if (graphic.getDojoShape()){
                graphic.getDojoShape().moveToFront();
            }
            positionIndexMapInfo(graphic);
        }

        // Move tooltip next to selected point
        function positionIndexMapInfo(graphic){
            var pos = domGeom.position(graphic.getNode());
            $('#index-map-info').css({
                'top': pos.y - (pos.h/2) - 3,
                'left': pos.x + pos.w
            }).show();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I ended up removing the "extent" line and used "center" and increased my "zoom" . It was a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [JS Extent Helper](https://arcgis-js-api-extent-helper.gavinr.com/) to get the xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax.